# Problem displaying database records using bootstrap productcard form

Tags: php

I want to display records from database into specific places using Bootstrap productcard, it used to work with a classic HTML table but I don't know why it doesn't now, can you explain to me what's wrong?

It outputs me an uncaught error: call to a member function mysqli_fetch_assoc...

```
<?php
    include_once('config/db.php');
    $sql = "SELECT tytul, opis, rodzaj, cena, lokalizacja, data_dod, data_wyg FROM ogloszenia";
    $zap = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $sql->mysqli_fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <div class="container ogloszenia">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pcard col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header">Zlecenie</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><?php $row['tytul']?></h5>
                            <p class="card-text"><?php $row['opis']?></p>
                            <p class="card-text"><?php $row['rodzaj']?></p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Zlecenie</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item">Cena: <?php $row['cena']?>zł</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><?php $row['lokalizacja']?></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><?php $row['data_dod']?></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item deadliner"><?php $row['data_wyg']?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes, i am sure. I still don't know what is the problem.

Comment: try changing to: `$row = $zap->mysqli_fetch_assoc()`